# Targeting a stateless replica on the same node when communicating over the ServiceProxy client

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have deployed two **Stateless** and `SinglePartion` Microservices into a Service Fabric cluster, which are hosted on Azure. Now I want to hook up the communication between these services like this:[image]

My *Masterdata Web API Service* should prefer to communicate with a *Masterdata ServiceProxy Service* replica/instance on the same node when calling a method via the ServiceProxy client. If there's no replica/instance available on the same node, connect to another node. The code looks like this:

```cs
var serviceClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IMasterDataServiceProxy>(new Uri("fabric:/sfApp/MasterDataServiceProxy"));
var result = await serviceClient.GetMasterData();
```

But actually the communication is like this:

[image]

The ServiceProxy connects to a randomly chosen replica/instance (due to `TargetReplicaSelector.Default`). I'm missing some communication options like "`TargetReplicaSelector.PreferSameNode`". Is there any way to handle this manually?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a good explanation:
[How can I reach a specific replica of a stateless service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480872/how-can-i-reach-a-specific-replica-of-a-stateless-service/37555012)

If you still really want it, either

- use http listeners on localhost or
- use a stateful service (using StateManager is optional)

Answer (score 3):

Not with Service Remoting (ServiceProxy), but with HTTP sure! Just grab the current node IP and make a request to your other service URL.

Of course, that does mean your Masterdata ServiceProxy Service would have to change to a Masterdata Web API Service.