# How to send data to a specified singleton instance in service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In my service fabric environment, I would like to send data to a specified singleton instance. If I use the create service proxy function I can only use the logical url like this:

```
var client = ServiceProxy.Create<IServiceInterface>(new Uri(“fabric:/platform/service”), ServicePartitionKey.Singleton, TargetReplicaSelector.RandomInstance);
```

TargetReplicaSelector gives me only the RandomInstanc option. Random Instance is really not working for me. I Can easily lookup all available singleton instances in my environment with:

```
var resolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault(); var partition = await resolver.ResolveAsync(new Uri(“fabric:/platform/service”), ServicePartitionKey.Singleton, new CancellationToken()); var endpoints
= partition.Endpoints;
```

but I cannot create a ServiceProxy from the endpoint data I receive.

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTTP communication for that.

Have a look at this thread: [Targeting a stateless replica on the same node when communicating over the ServiceProxy client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721138/targeting-a-stateless-replica-on-the-same-node-when-communicating-over-the-servi/)